# SQL code to alert user if the above script fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I currently have an SMS client using MySQL. The problem i am having is that when the code is being executed i do not get alerted if the script had run succsefully or failed. There for if the script failed to run the data i currently held is lost.

So my question is what method or approach i would require in order to allow my script to run as per usual but i need a way of being alerted via email if the script had run succesfully or any problems occured.

Is there a way of setting up an if statement in my sql workbench for example

If the script run succesfull email example@example.co.uk "script run succesfully"

Else

email example@example.co.uk "a problem occured during this script"

Could this be set up onto a timer so say an email would be sent every 6 hours ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume if your script runs into problems, you kick out some sort of error code. Or, if successful, you kick out a success code.  If you have these in place, you can have it redirected to call some sort of monitoring capability that will, in real time, be able to kick out the email.  I guess you'll also want to log the event, with time stamp, so you can go in and do any fixing or analysis.

Check out developer.alertcaster.com

Though you already have a SMS client in place, you can use the monitoring-reporting-alerting capabilities it offers.  Further, you can attached unique events in your script and it will keep track of it all for you.  Also, if there is something catastrophic that happens, it will make a phone call to you - however you want to configure.